# cost function increases

Tags: machine-learning

Any idea what will cause the cost function to increase with iteration in machine learning, beside a too high learning rate. The learning rate was high and I was getting oscillations of the cost functions and I lowered it from 1 to 0.001, now the cost function is increasing. I have inserted a picture of cost vs iteration.
[image]

here is some of the other variables:

- dimension reduction method: PCA,
- num of dimension: 676,
- num of iterations: 1000
- learning rate: 0.0010
- reglarization constant: 0.50

Comment: What kind of model are you fitting?

Comment: if you are referring to supervised v.s. unsupervised... supervised.

Comment: That, and is this a linear model or a non-linear one? How are you fitting it?

Comment: hmmm... good question, the features are the rgb values of a picture. I did not raise them to any power. So I would assume linear. and I am using gradient descent.

Comment: That's not what I meant, but never mind. Check whether you haven't accidentally implemented gradient *ascent* instead of *descent*, and whether your cost function and gradient definitions are correct.

Comment: How are you measuring the cost?